# Display different types of files in a carousel tabs

Tags: codenameone

I need to implement a carousel to show images/video/pdf/ppt files. I used Tab component to achieve it. But it's not working as expected. The first tab displays image correctly but at the same time pdf file gets opened which is there on the third tab. Second tab video does not play. I tried calling these events on tab selection but still not working. My code as below.

```
    Form hi = new Form("Swipe Tabs", new LayeredLayout());

    Tabs t = new Tabs();
    t.hideTabs();

    container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY();
    container2 = BoxLayout.encloseY();
    container3 = BoxLayout.encloseY();

    InputStream is = null; 
    ImageViewer iv = null;

    try{
        is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/Img1.png");
        iv = new ImageViewer(Image.createImage(is));
    }catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }

    container1 = BoxLayout.encloseY(iv);


    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    fs.mkdir(fs.getAppHomePath());

    String fileName = fs.getAppHomePath() + "test.mp4";

    if(!fs.exists(fileName)) {
        Util.downloadUrlToFile("http://localhost/app/test.mp4", fileName, true);
    }
    try{
        Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(fileName, true);
        video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
        container2 = BoxLayout.encloseY(new MediaPlayer(video));       
        video.play();
    }catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }


    fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    fs.mkdir(fs.getAppHomePath());
    final String fileName1 = fs.getAppHomePath() + "file1.pdf";
    if(!fs.exists(fileName1)) {
        Util.downloadUrlToFile("http://localhost/app/file1.pdf", fileName1, true);
    }
    container3 = BoxLayout.encloseY();
    Display.getInstance().execute(fileName1);


    t.addTab("Tab1", container1);
    t.addTab("Tab2", container2);
    t.addTab("Tab3", container3);

    new ButtonGroup(firstTab, secondTab, thirdTab);
    firstTab.setSelected(true);
    Container tabsFlow = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(firstTab, secondTab, thirdTab);

    hi.add(t);
    hi.add(BorderLayout.south(tabsFlow));
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Display.execute` launches an external viewer to display something. It doesn't create a component you can embed. We don't support embedding a PDF as that isn't available on Android and is a bit flaky on iOS. If you only care about iOS you can use a `BrowserComponent` to show a PDF. You can use a button and invoke `execute` when the button is pressed to show a PDF.

Change this:

```
    container2 = BoxLayout.encloseY(new MediaPlayer(video));       
    video.play();
```

To:

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(video);
    container2 = mp;       
    mp.setAutoplay(true);
    mp.setLoop(true);
```

Finally, I would suggest using `Log.e()` not `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Thanks Shai for your reply and suggestions. For the video component I used your suggested code, added mp.showControls();  method to it and executed in NB. But the the video control did not play automatically and the controls buttons were not displayed.                    I installed the same app on an Android device, and there the video control itself was not visible. Please suggest.

Comment: You did use a proper URL for the video and not localhost right? Did you tap it?

Comment: Yes, the URL used is correct and not the local host.

Comment: Instead of a container, I used a form and I could run it in the Tab now.                                   
            Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(fileName, true);            
            hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));

Comment: Regarding display of a PDF file, I tried to show it in the BrowserComponent but it doesn't display anything. I tested it on an Android device.                                                                                                                    
        Form hi = new Form("Browser", new BorderLayout());
        BrowserComponent browser = new BrowserComponent();
        browser.setURL(""http://192.168.0.4/app/CSMCoaching.pdf");               
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);                                                                  
        hi.show();

Comment: Apart from external viewer, is there any way to open the PDF file in the carousel? I tried opening it in browsercomponent but that didn't work.

Comment: As I said, I browser component would **only** work on iOS. There is no support for showing PDFs elsewhere.